# I need help with simple algebra with logarithms

Tags: logarithms

Can anyone help me with this?
$$xe^{ht} = y $$
How do I eliminate "t" from the LHS of the equation? What I want to end up with is the LHS being a function of "h".

Comment: Do you mean that you want to isolate $t$ on one side of the equation?

Comment: @Allawonder Basically I would like the "t" to only appear on the right hand side of the equation. I want the left hand side of equation to just have some function of "x" and "h". By implication I don't "x" or "h" on the right hand side either. I want to isolate "x" and "h" on the left hand side. Hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that $$e^{ht}=\frac yx,$$ or that $$ht=\log\left(\frac yx\right).$$ Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$xe^{ht}=y$$
$$ln(xe^{ht})=ln(y)$$
$$ln(x)+ht=ln(y)$$
$$ht=ln(y)-ln(x)=ln(\frac{y}{x})$$
$$h=\frac{ln(\frac{y}{x})}{t}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$xe^{ht}=x(e^h)^t=y$$

$$(e^h)^t=\frac{y}{x}$$

$$e^h=\bigg(\frac{y}{x}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{t}}$$

Provided that $x,t\neq 0$.